# Rails framework & Nginx web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

As we install rails it uses its own web server WEBrick. If i want to run ths application in Nginx server, then how to configure or set the Nginx web werver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run your rails application in a production server such as mongrel_cluster or [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) (I have used the former, and am currently switching to the latter). To put nginx in front of it, I would use the [upstream and proxy_pass directives](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule). I found a nice [blog post](http://kovyrin.net/2006/08/22/high-performance-rails-nginx-lighttpd-mongrel/) comparing ways of running rails applications that shows their config for mongrel_cluster + nginx.

[Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is also available for nginx, I've used that with Apache and it was very easy to set up.

Comment: No problem :) Was that everything you needed?