# How to deploy Rails project in Nginx server using passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, passenger

In my local, I am using `werbrick` application server for my localhost.

I have Ruby version 1.9.2 .and Rails version 3.1.

> How to deploy On live,with Rails Project On Nginx Server?
>
> And What will be the application server (like passenger module with apache) can be used with Nginx server for Rails 3.1 application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails fraemework & Nginx web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897298/rails-fraemework-nginx-web-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://trevorturk.com/2010/09/22/passenger-with-nginx-on-mac-os-x-2nd-edition-2/) should give you a good starting point. [This one here](http://shapeshed.com/installing-passenger-3-with-rvm-and-nginx-on-osx/) goes a little deeper in detail. Note: I used these to get nginx running on my local development machine (OSX 10.7) and to host different rails apps locally without using Webrick. Probably there is more to take  care of on a live / production system.

Comment: Thanks frank... its really nice...!